# IBM Mobilefirst persistent data table load

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In IBM Mobilefirst 8.0 how often does **`MFP_PERSISTENT_DATA`** table is updated? Once per adapter call by client? What load on this table can one expect?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [MFP Internal tables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/r_internal_ibm_worklight_database_tables.html) on all the runtime databases and why they are used.

Persistent Data is primarily used for the following purposes:

1. Client Registration Data ( information about every registered client instance (device and application pair) including information about the device, application, usernames associated with the client, last activity time and additional custom attributes.)
2. Client Security Context : ( authentication state of the client. The size of the data depends on the number of the security checks used by the application, and the size of the state data stored by each security check.)

Load on the DB would primarily depend on how often the states of the above entries change. In general, it will be created on client registration and updated on every access of the client - updating "Last activity time" column. If adapter code deals with "Custom attributes" and updates ClientRegistrationData, this will in turn lead to persistent data update.

I would say it is directly proportional to the number of active instances and depends on various factors like Security check state, Custom attributes usage .